# Issue when converting a tuple to a string

Tags: python

I don't know a lot about python so please be patient with me:

Let's say we have a tuple that has this form:

```
 locations = [('John' , 32 , 21) , ('Michael' , 23 , 12)]
```

How can I concatenate them to a string that looks like

"John 32 21

Michael 23 12"

I tried doing this:

```
str1 = '\n'.join( ' '.join(elem[0] elem [1] elem[2]) for elem in locations)
```

But I get an error at the elem[0],[1],[2] saying **Invalid Syntax**

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: The "issue" is it isn't valid syntax.

Comment: What you have is a list, not a tuple.

Comment: i meant to say a list of tuples but I thought it was wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> '\n'.join(' '.join(str(y) for y in x) for x in locations)
'John 32 21\nMichael 23 12'
```

Answer (score 2):

[edit] Or try this

```
>>> '\n'.join([' '.join(map(lambda c: str(c), elem)) for elem in locations])
>>> 'John 32 21\nMichael 23 12'
```

map(lambda c: str(c), elem) takes every element from locations ie from ('John' , 32 , 21) 'John', 32 and 21 and converts into string and returns ['John', '32', '21'] which is then join using ' ' and finally by '\n'

Updated:

```
>>> '\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, elem)) for elem in locations])
```

learned, thanks

Comment: The lambda isn't necessary in this case (`map(str, elem)`).  Without it, this would be the shortest answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
>>>['%s %s %s' %i for i in locations]
['John 32 21', 'Michael 23 12']
```

with line feed:

```
>>>print '\n'.join(['%s %s %s' %i for i in locations])
John 32 21 
Michael 23 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own code need to have each elem separated by a comma and the three elements wrapped inside a container:

```
 ' '.join(elem[0] elem [1] elem[2]) # invalid syntax, join takes a single iterable

'\n'.join( ' '.join((str(elem[0]), str(elem[1]) ,str(elem[2]))) for elem in locations)
```

You can use unpacking and map to do the same:

```
'\n'.join( ' '.join(map(str,(a,b,c))) for a,b,c in locations)
```

Or simply:

```
 '\n'.join( ' '.join(map(str,elem)) for elem in locations)
```